# How do I get the attributes from an object array?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model variable called companies with an object array type. By putting it to the console I get this:

This object is loaded with the fetch function:

```
require(["collections/Companies"],
    function(Companies) {
    var companies = new Companies();
    companies.fetch();
    console.log(companies[0].get("name"));

});
```

[image: companies]

companies.js:

```
define([
    'models/Company'
], function(CompanyModel) {
    'use strict';

    var CompanyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: CompanyModel,
        url: 'scripts/data/companies.json'
    });

    return CompanyCollection;
});
```

company.js:

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    var CompanyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            description: ''
        }
    });

    return CompanyModel;
});
```

I have tried to get the attributes by using get according to the [tutorials](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/) (`console.log(companies[0].get("name"));`) with no luck.

What is the correct syntax to get the attributes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `companies[0].attributes.name` or `companies[0].attributes["name"]` Access it like how it's shown on the screenshot! :)

Comment: Both companies[0].attributes.name or companies[0].attributes["name"] throws TypeError: companies[0] is undefined in log.

Comment: I think we're missing something here then, as per vanilla JavaScript that's certainly how you'd access a DOMNode Attribute.

Comment: don't think accessing using "attributes" is a good idea. backbone js has `model.get(attributename)` method to access attributes... Check if `companies[0]` is a valid object and is a backbone model with "name" attribute defined.

Comment: The model contains the name, id and desc attributes defined, but companies[0] is still undefined according to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get model from collection you can use Backbone collection method - collection.at(INDEX);

Example code:

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
collection.add({ id: 1, name: "S"});
collection.add({ id: 2, name: "F"});

console.log(collection.at(0).attributes); // { id: 1, name: "S"}

var model = collection.at(0);

// get attributes from model

console.log(model.get("name")); // "S"
```

You can play with [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CP7NS/1/)

To get models from collection use : collection.models (you will get array of models)

Answer (score 1):

Since `name` is a property inside `attributes` which is an object, you can use:

```
console.log(companies[0].attributes.name);
```

Comment: Both companies[0].attributes.name or companies[0].attributes["name"] throws TypeError: companies[0] is undefined in log.

Comment: How do you initialize your model? Can you post your code?

Comment: I have edited the question with the models and code.

Answer (score 0):

the object you are printing is Backbone Collection. You need to access the model using `collection.models` array.

```
var name = companies.models[0].get("name");
```

As per the documentation, you should access the model using `collection.get` method given the model id or using `collection.at` method given index.

So, you could access your company object as:

```
var company = companies.get(1000001);
var name = company.get("name");
```

Documentation:
http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models

Comment: TypeError: company is undefined with the exact same code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the second picture this should work:

```
require(["collections/Companies"],
    function(Companies) {
    var companies = new Companies();
    companies.fetch();
    for (var idx in companies){
        console.log(companies[idx].attributes.name);
    }
});
```

There is no `companies[0]` only `companies[1000001]` and `companies[1000002]`.

Comment: I do understand that the indexes are 1000001 and 1000002 but the companies[anything] is still undefined.